# even if i give correct login username and password its not login. its showing login failed

Tags: javascript, html

```
function validate()
{
    var username=document.getElementById("username").Value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").Value;
    if(username=="yogi"&& password=="venky")
    {
        alert("login succesfully");
        return false;
        window.open("");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("login failed");
    }
}
```

-i cannot login with correct login password. it showing alert login failed.
what to do?

Answer (score 1):

it is `value` not `Value`

```
function validate()
{
    var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(username=="yogi"&& password=="venky")
    {
        alert("login succesfully");
        return false;
        window.open("");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("login failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in Value. It should be value

```js
function validate()
{
    var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(username=="yogi"&& password=="venky")
    {
        alert("login succesfully");
        return false;
        window.open("");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("login failed");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id='username' />
<input id='password' />
<button onclick='validate()'>Send</button>
```